# How a client would discover the IP address of a server?

Tags: tcp, ip, client-server

Given a subnetwork (connected to the Internet) containing one web server and a handful number of clients, how one new client willing to join the network would know which host is the web server ?
The web server has a static IP Address which the new client does not know about. The aim is to discover the IP address of the server dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using network range scanner like nmap.

It will basically scan for web server listening on port 80 HTTP or 443 HTTPS trough whole subnet from within the network.